# "DataTable is not a function" $-issue/-conflict (jQuery and new theme)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, load, datatables

Since changing to a new theme I have some probs including **[DataTables](https://datatables.net)**. jQuery is only called once and it is placed at the correct position, so basically everything correct.

I receive messages like

```
    TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

or

```
    TypeError: $ is undefined
```

Beneath the *DataTables* I have a different JS with load() and with a similar problem. There I could fix it while putting this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

before this:

```
    $("#tmp").load("tmp.htm")
```

I've read on some boards, that there could be an issue with the place-holder **$**. Anyway, the part above solves my problem. But back to the DataTables. I think it's the same problem, but I'm unable to understand the problem.

My Table starts with:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {              
    var tabelle = $('#mytable').DataTable(
```

But with this before..

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

I do only get errors. Could somebody please help me?

**++++++++ UPDATE ++++++++**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$.fn.dataTable.pipeline = function ( opts ) {
    // Configuration options
    var conf = $.extend( {
        pages: 5,     // number of pages to cache
        url: '',      // script url
        data: null,   // function or object with parameters to send to the server
                      // matching how `ajax.data` works in DataTables
        method: 'GET' // Ajax HTTP method
    }, opts );

    // Private variables for storing the cache
    var cacheLower = -1;
    var cacheUpper = null;
    var cacheLastRequest = null;
    var cacheLastJson = null;

    return function ( request, drawCallback, settings ) {
        var ajax          = false;
        var requestStart  = request.start;
        var requestLength = request.length;
        var requestEnd    = requestStart + requestLength;

        if ( settings.clearCache ) {
            // API requested that the cache be cleared
            ajax = true;
            settings.clearCache = false;
        }
        else if ( cacheLower < 0 || requestStart < cacheLower || requestEnd > cacheUpper ) {
            // outside cached data - need to make a request
            ajax = true;
        }
        else if ( JSON.stringify( request.order )   !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.order ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.columns ) !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.columns ) ||
                  JSON.stringify( request.search )  !== JSON.stringify( cacheLastRequest.search )
        ) {
            // properties changed (ordering, columns, searching)
            ajax = true;
        }

        // Store the request for checking next time around
        cacheLastRequest = $.extend( true, {}, request );

        if ( ajax ) {
            // Need data from the server
            if ( requestStart < cacheLower ) {
                requestStart = requestStart - (requestLength*(conf.pages-1));

                if ( requestStart < 0 ) {
                    requestStart = 0;
                }
            }

            cacheLower = requestStart;
            cacheUpper = requestStart + (requestLength * conf.pages);

            request.start = requestStart;
            request.length = requestLength*conf.pages;

            // Provide the same `data` options as DataTables.
            if ( $.isFunction ( conf.data ) ) {
                // As a function it is executed with the data object as an arg
                // for manipulation. If an object is returned, it is used as the
                // data object to submit
                var d = conf.data( request );
                if ( d ) {
                    $.extend( request, d );
                }
            }
            else if ( $.isPlainObject( conf.data ) ) {
                // As an object, the data given extends the default
                $.extend( request, conf.data );
            }

            settings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
                "type":     conf.method,
                "url":      conf.url,
                "data":     request,
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache":    false,
                "success":  function ( json ) {
                    cacheLastJson = $.extend(true, {}, json);

                    if ( cacheLower != requestStart ) {
                        json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
                    }
                    json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

                    drawCallback( json );
                }
            } );
        }
        else {
            json = $.extend( true, {}, cacheLastJson );
            json.draw = request.draw; // Update the echo for each response
            json.data.splice( 0, requestStart-cacheLower );
            json.data.splice( requestLength, json.data.length );

            drawCallback(json);
        }
    }
};


$.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'clearPipeline()', function () {
    return this.iterator( 'table', function ( settings ) {
        settings.clearCache = true;
    } );
} );

        $(document).ready(function() {

                var tabelle = $('#mytable').DataTable( 
                {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true, 
                "ajax": $.fn.dataTable.pipeline( 
                            {
                            url: 'source.htm',
                            pages: 1
                            } 
                        ),              
                .....
                } 
            );              

        } );
    </script>
```

Comment: The errors you state imply that either jQuery (`$`) or DataTables (`$.DataTable`) are not being loaded correctly, or are being accessed in the wrong order. Can you please add your full initialisation code and the HTML which includes these scripts.

Comment: can you check whether datatable library is included below jquery library.

Comment: @Hoja.M.A As I said in the introduction, the sorting is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves the problem. Adding the line below the initiating body-tag:

```
<script> $ = jQuery; </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem and the code below solves the issue

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){`